# How to set classification of an email automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, vba, powershell, outlook

I have the following powershell script:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "receiver@host.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Hello"
$Mail.Body ="World"
$Mail.Send()
```

But when I execute it I have to select classification of the email manually: there appears a **TITUS pop up** with a the "Select Classification" title select box containing the following items: Public, For Internal Use Only and Private. I have to select an item and click "OK", after that the email is sent.

The script is supposed to be a job that gets run on schedule, so I don't want to interact with the script at all.

I have already walked through [the whole msdn page of MailItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties%28v=office.14%29.aspx) but I didn't come across anything similar to Classificaiton. What did I miss?

I am not an administrator of the server, so I don't have access to change anything.

PS: I selected the C# tag just because C# has the same API to interact with Outlook

Comment: You may want to disable any add-ins you've got turned on in your localized copy of Outlook.  Looks like, possibly, "Titus," from my quick search lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Outlook, just like any other Office app, is not designed to be used in unattended scenarios. It can and will display modal prompts out of the blue.

Secondly, to send a message, you can use straight SMTP, [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600292(v=exchg.150).aspx), [Extended MAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815424.aspx) (C++ or Delphi only),  or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - its [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of objects wraps Extended MAPI and can be accessed for many language).

In your particular case, it sure looks like a custom third-party addin displaying a dialog box.

Comment: So, you think this is not an Outlook built-in feature?

Comment: No, it is not. What does it show if you click Help?

Comment: Turned out it is a TITUS pop up. Have you come across it? Do you know how to deal with it?

Comment: No, I have not heard anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

The mail object is not able to set the classification of the email object. If you pipe the object to Get-Member, you will see that there is no changeable property for the classification and/or a method to change it. You can find this by running the following command:

```
$Mail | Get-Member
```

Additionally, if you look at the list of properties there is not one that looks related to classification.

```
$Mail | Format-List
```

---

This [blog post](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2011/05/sending-message-with-classification-in.html) will probably help you, but it seems more complex than the solution you're looking for. This one utilizes Exchange instead of the Outlook client.